# object visible actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript

Hello I am making a simple actionscript game and i want to reveal an image when i click on a movieclip.

I am trying to use the object.visible = false; method however it doesnt seem to be working for me .

Basically when i click on the "clown" movie clip, i want the "elephant" image to appear

```
function myClickFunction(event:MouseEvent) {
    if (clown.visible){
        clown.visible = false;
    } else {
        elephant.visible = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is a bit muddled. If I understand what you're looking for, you should be able to change it to the following to have the clown disappear and the elephant appear when the clown is clicked.

```
function myClickFunction(event:MouseEvent) {
    if (clown.visible){
        clown.visible = false;
        elephant.visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes sorry I am a beginner at actionscript! I gave that a go and it isn't causing any error's however it still isn't working for me